# jQuery serialize function with multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to use jQuery to post multiple values to PHP page, and then use that values as a single values.

I start with code from Jquery site :

```
  <form ><br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
   <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
   <option>Multiple2</option>
   <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

  <br>

 <br>

 </form>

 <p><tt id="results"></tt></p>

  <script>
     function showValues() {
     var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
     $( "#results" ).text( str );
                            }
    $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
    $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
   showValues();
    </script>
```

Result is: `multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple2`, and that is fine.

Now mycproblem is how to post these values to `test.php` page, and then to use unique values, like this :

```
$multiple=[first value]
$multiple2=[second value]
etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `multiple` to `multiple[]` in your form. This will submit your values as multiple[]=1st value, multiple[]=2nd value and more.

jQuery,

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  formData=$('form').serialize();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("Form submitted");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Error in form submission");
        }
    });
});
```

At the PHP end,

```
$multiple=$_POST['multiple']; // Get the array input
```

Now proceed with the values respectively,

```
foreach($multiple as $key => $value)
{
echo "value number $key is $value"; // This will print as value number 0 is 1st value, value number 1 is 2nd value and more.
}
```

Comment: Tnx a lot! Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

You have to post the form to test.php using AJAX. Try this -

```
$("form").on('submit', function(ev){

    ev.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var action = 'test.php';
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(action, data)
    .done(function(response){

        if(response.success == false)
        {
            // If failed
        }
        else
        {
            // If successfully submitted
        }
    });
});
```

And on the other side (test.php), you'll get an array of your multiple values like this,

```
$multiple1 = $_POST['multiple']['0'];
$multiple2 = $_POST['multiple']['1'];
```