# How to send select2 multiple selected option values with form.serialize()?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I used select2 to select multiple options in html and want to send selected values as an array with form.serialize() to update database field and I have other input in my form. How can I do this?

html:

```
<html>
<select name="number" id="number" required class="js-example basic-multiple" multiple="multiple[]">
<option class="select_option" value="1" >1</option>
<option class="select_option" value="2" >2</option>
<option class="select_option" value="3" >3</option>
</select>
</html>
```

I want to send  [1,2,3] as part of form.serialize().

Answer (score 1):

I had mistake in html part. [], should be after name of the select tag, not multiple attribute. so It should be:

```
<html>
<select name="number[]" id="number" required class="js-example basic-multiple" 
multiple="multiple">
<option class="select_option" value="1" >1</option>
<option class="select_option" value="2" >2</option>
<option class="select_option" value="3" >3</option>
</select>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my understanding I think you want to achieve this.

```
$(window).click( function (e) {
          // if a submit button is clicked
          if (e.target.matches('#submit-button')) {
            // get the action url of the form you are submiting 
            var actionUrl = e.currentTarget.action
            $.ajax({
                url: actionUrl,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                // include the form you are submiting
                data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
                complete: function () {
                 console.log('form successfully submitted')
               }
            });
          }
        });
```

Let me know if you want something different.

Comment: I have found that I can do it with multiple attribute in selection tag. but, still it doesn't work.

Comment: The straight forward way is to use a ```select``` tag  to send one ```option```. But perhaps you can use checkbox. Or you can create three ```select``` tags with ```option[1], option[2], option[3]``` as values respectively.

Comment: I use select2 for selecting more than one option.

Comment: Im trying to say that. form.serialize() needs inputs with different names to work properyl.

Comment: Here is what I found  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955029/10742220. but multiple option doesn't work.